# Raw array of shared_ptr<X> where X doesn't seem to be initialised?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a class:

```
class C{
public:
//Omitted

private:
    shared_ptr<X> anArray[2];
};
```

and `X` looks like:

```
class X{
public:
    X(); //default constructor used by the above array declaration?
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, double> a;
};
```

After I create my `C` class, I access one of the two shared_ptr objects in the array, however, the memory doesn't seem to be initialised. By this I mean `X::a` doesn't have any valid state.

I thought the array declaration in `C` would create the `shared_ptr<X>`s AND the `X` objects?

Is there something I should be explicitly doing in the X default constructor?

Comment: The default constructor for `shared_ptr<T>` absolutely does *not* create a new instance of `T`. If it did, there would be no way to have an 'empty pointer', the smart pointer equivalent of `NULL`.

Comment: @aruisdante how can I "insert"/"assign" a T object to each element of the array, inside the C constructor?

Comment: And what should the shared pointers actually point to?

Comment: Also read about [constructors and member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know about constructors and member initializer lists, its the fact this is a shared_ptr which is throwing me :)

Comment: If it wasn't a shared pointer, but instead e.g.`X* anArray[2]` you would not expect the actual pointers to be initialized, would you? It's the same with the smart pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default constructor for `std::shared_ptr<X>` absolutely does **not** create a new instance of `X`. It does this to allow for creating an 'empty pointer', the smart pointer equivalent of `NULL`, so that a default constructed smart pointer is analogous to a 'default constructed' raw pointer.

To get what you want, you simply need to initialize the `anArray` instance in the constructor's initialization list, like so:

```
class C: {

public:
    C() : anArray({std::shared_ptr<X>(new X()), std::shared_ptr<X>(new X())}) // ...
    {
       // rest of constructor
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<X> anArray[2];
};
```

Alternatively you can use `std::make_shared<X>()` in the initialization list instead of `std::shared_ptr<X>(new X())` as it's a bit more efficient and slightly safer with respect to exceptions causing memory leaks. I left the 'raw' form in so it was more explicit as to what was happening.

Comment: Ah the array requires an initialiser list! Thank you!

Comment: Nitpick: if the default constructor *did* act that way, it would be easy enough to modify the API to allow constructing a null pointer: e.g. a constructor taking `nullptr_t` argument.

Comment: @Hurkyl Sure I suppose that's true, but then you're making `shared_ptr<X> x_ptr;` mean something different than `X* x_ptr;` Since the point of smart pointers is to make them act as close as possible in look/feel to regular pointers, that wouldn't be desirable. I meant more it would be impossible with the current API than impossible from a technical standpoint.

Comment: @aruisdante: I agree that it would be a bad design to have `shared_ptr` act that way; I just think the second sentence is misleading. (also, very much not deserving of being the first justification of the current design)

Comment: But, given the fact that the API to `std::shared_ptr` is what it is, what I said is technically correct. If that wasn't the behavior of the default constructor, there would be no way to have a `NULL` equivalent shared pointer. I'll edit the text though if you want.